# Oracle PL/SQL Bulk Collect into one column of collection based on condition

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulk, collect

I have the following table in one schema: `User_Codes(useri_id, user_code)`. I want to access this table from another schema in a stored proc and minimize the number of round trips between schemas.

In the stored proc I have a collection containing user data along with user ids. I want to fetch corresponding user_codes from other schema using the user_ids. So assuming that `rowset` is a collection or SQL TABLE containing user data with filled user_ids and to be filled user_codes, what I want is something like this:

```
select uc.user_code
bulk collect into rowset.user_code
from other_schema.user_codes uc
where uc.user_id in (
 select distinct rowset_table.user_id
 from table(rowset) rowset_table
 where rowset_table.user_id is not null
);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but maybe this works for you:

```
select rs.user_id, uc.user_code
  bulk collect into rowset
  from other_schema.user_codes uc, table(rowset) rs
  where uc.user_id = rs.user_id;
```